# Minimum possible permissions for a Win7 user to login?

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, login, sandbox

On my Win7 Pro x64 system, I would like to run a program I have 99% confidence in (specifically, [Blitzgewitter](http://www.pouet.net/prod.php?which=62970) by Titan).  However, on the off chance of a trojan, I would like to run it in a sandboxed user account.

What are the minimum necessary permissions for a user account (say, "scener") to login, download the file to `%USERPROFILE%`, and run it?  I'd appreciate any advice before I start trying something since I don't want to get into login failures.

I have two thoughts:

1. Remove scener from the Users group and set Allow Read for scener on C:\Windows and C:\Program Files, Allow RW on `%TEMP%`, and Allow All on C:\users\scener.
2. Leave scener in the Users group but Deny everything except R on C:\Windows and C:\Program Files and RW on `%TEMP%`.

What say you?

Comment: If the software is to run sandboxed like this anyway, I would strongly consider running it inside a VM. Then you can isolate it as much as you want to, and not have to worry about specific permissions.

Comment: http://www.sandboxie.com/  This is specifically for sand boxing individual apps.